# Converting SQL Server query to DB2

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I am trying to convert the following SQL server query to DB2 or mysql...Can you please help me here..

```
SELECT 
    *,
    CASE 
        WHEN PATINDEX('%S%LD%', orderstatus) > 0 
            THEN 'Sold'
        WHEN PATINDEX('%STOCK%', orderstatus) > 0 
             OR PATINDEX('%STK%[0-9]/[0-9]%', orderstatus) > 0 
            THEN 'Stock' 
        ELSE'' 
    END AS comment,
    CASE 
        WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]/[0-9]%', orderstatus) > 0 
             OR CHARINDEX('*', orderstatus) > 0 
             OR CHARINDEX('BAM', orderstatus) > 0
            THEN 'BAM' 
            ELSE'' 
    END AS BAMYN,
    CASE 
        WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]/[0-9]%', orderstatus) > 0 
            THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(orderstatus, CHARINDEX('/', orderstatus) - 2, 5) + '/2022' AS DATE)
            ELSE orddate 
    END AS soldorstockdate 
FROM 
    input
```

Wondering how `CHARINDEX` and `PATINDEX` would be replaced in DB2 or mysql?

**Query Tried:**

```
SELECT a.*, CASE WHEN REGEXP_COUNT(ORDERSTATUS,'SLD')>0 THEN 'Sold' 
  WHEN REGEXP_COUNT ('%STOCK%',ORDERSTATUS)>0 OR REGEXP_COUNT ('STK[0-9]/[0-9]',ORDERSTATUS)>0 THEN 'Stock' ELSE'' END AS comment 
         ,CASE WHEN REGEXP_COUNT('[0-9]/[0-9]',ORDERSTATUS)>0 OR LOCATE('*',ORDERSTATUS)>0 OR LOCATE('BAM',ORDERSTATUS)>0
               THEN 'BAM' ELSE'' END AS BAMYN 
         ,CASE WHEN REGEXP_COUNT('[0-9]/[0-9]',ORDERSTATUS)>0 
               THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(ORDERSTATUS,LOCATE('/',ORDERSTATUS)-2,5) AS DATE)
               ELSE ORDDATE  END AS soldorstockdate 


FROM input  a
```

I am getting the following error (AS 400)

SQL Error [2201S]: [SQ20558] Regular expression string for function REGEXP_COUNT not valid.

Comment: What platform and version of Db2?  Have you looked at the docs?  What have you tried?

Comment: Hi @Charles....I am using Dbeaver Version 22.0.0.202203060510...Not sure how to look at the DB2 version...Can you please guide me

Comment: Dbeaver version doesn't matter... and the SQL required depends on the platform.

Comment: Hi Charles...Its 7.3..

Comment: what platform?  That's either a very old LUW or z/OS or a relatively newer version for IBM i.

Comment: Hi Charles..Its i series...

Comment: @user3369545 Look at the [REGEXP_COUNT](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=functions-regexp-count) function.

Comment: Hi @MarkBarinstein: Thank you so much for your response...Also just wanted to understand if LOCATE would be the equivalent of CHARINDEX

Comment: Also I am getting the following error that SQL Error [2201S]: [SQ20558] Regular expression string for function REGEXP_COUNT not valid.

Comment: Hi @Charles: I am using db2-400

Comment: @user3369545 Pattern must be the 2-nd argument of REGEXP_COUNT, not the 1-st one. Use LOCATE, If you need just to find a constant substring - there is no need to invoke the function with more complex processing capabilities. LOCATE doesn't support regular expressions.

Comment: Hi @MarkBarinstein: I am still getting the error SQL Error [2201S]: [SQ20558] Regular expression string for function REGEXP_COUNT not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following as is.
If this returns wrong result, then provide some data example in the same form and the result desired.

```
SELECT 
  a.*
, CASE 
    WHEN REGEXP_COUNT (ORDERSTATUS, 'S.*LD') <> 0 
      THEN 'Sold' 
    WHEN REGEXP_COUNT (ORDERSTATUS, 'STOCK|STK[0-9]{2}') <> 0 
      THEN 'Stock' 
    ELSE '' 
  END AS comment 
, CASE 
    WHEN REGEXP_COUNT (ORDERSTATUS, '[0-9]/[0-9]|\*|BAM') <> 0
      THEN 'BAM' 
    ELSE '' 
  END AS BAMYN 
, COALESCE (DATE (TO_DATE (REGEXP_SUBSTR (ORDERSTATUS, '[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}') || '/2022', 'MM/DD/YYYY')), CURRENT DATE)  
      AS soldorstockdate 
FROM 
(
VALUES 'SooLD', 'STK12', 'STOCK', '1/2', 'BAM', 'ABC01/31DEF'
) A (ORDERSTATUS)
```

| ORDERSTATUS | COMMENT | BAMYN | SOLDORSTOCKDATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SooLD | Sold |  | 2022-05-27 |
| STK12 | Stock |  | 2022-05-27 |
| STOCK | Stock |  | 2022-05-27 |
| 1/2 |  | BAM | 2022-05-27 |
| BAM |  | BAM | 2022-05-27 |
| ABC01/31DEF |  | BAM | 2022-01-31 |

Answer (score 1):

In Db2-LUW, the nearest to CHARINDEX may be [LOCATE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-locate).

You might also use [REGEXP_EXTRACT](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-regexp-extract) if your Db2-server-platform and Db2-version (which you always need to know, z/os, i-series, linux/unix/windows/cloud) supports that.